# PHP counter for multiple variables for website

Tags: php, file-io, survey

I am looking to setup a Server that accepts a URL with a few variables in it which I'll use the $_GET statement to obtain. These variables will increment counters stored on the server. I was going to write these files to a file and then open it/write to it kind of like this http://www.developingwebs.net/phpclass/hitcounter.php however this is only showing for one variable. I changed the code to reflect multiple variables but am not entirely sure how to write the multiple variables to the file. I was using this:

```
$counters = ("counter.txt");
$increment = file($counters);
/* Bunch of if else ladders checking the $_GET statements and
   incrementing $increments[] accordingly */
for($i; $i < 16; $i++)          //write variables to file
    fputs($fp, $increment[$i]);
```

Where $fp points to the text file I was using and $increment[ ] holds the variables being incremented and such. So would this work? And would this work with multiple people accessing this URL at the same time? It needs to keep an accurate count of all the variables regardless of how many people are accessing the page.

Example: a survey submitted online with 4 questions. Each response has 4 options to it so in total 16 variables being stored. People will be submitting their responses to the server randomly and possibly at the same time. I need to parse their response and update the counter accordingly even when multiple people are submitting at the same time.

Thanks for any help, hope I supplied enough detail but if not just ask questions.

EDIT: The URL is being sent from an Android device to the Server I don't know if that changes anything but just wanted to be clear. The Android device is submitting the survey responses.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use files for this rather than something atomic, like a database?  Are you confident that you won't have two submissions happening at the same time, with a period of time when both instances will be trying to update the counter to the same value, thus missing counts and/or causing errors?  Do you not have an SQL database available?  [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) or [PostgreSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php) both work well in PHP, and will likely let you do what you want better than the way you've described in your question.

Comment: Yeah I think I might end up doing that in order to avoid race conditions and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Graham's comment, you'd be far better off letting your database server handle responses, and building your totals as part of a reporting system rather than part of the form submission process.

Here's an example, in sort-of-meta code.  First, your HTML form:

```
<form method="GET"> <!-- though I recommend POST instead -->
 <input type="checkbox" name="ch[1]"> Checkbox 1
 <input type="checkbox" name="ch[2]"> Checkbox 2
 <input type="checkbox" name="ch[3]"> Checkbox 3
</form>
```

Then, the PHP that receives the form:

```
<?php

  $qfmt = "INSERT INTO answers (question, answer) VALUES ('%s, '%s')";

  foreach ($ch as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 'Yes') {
      $query = sprintf($qfmt, $key, $value);
      mysql_query($query);
    }
  }

  print "<p>Thanks!</p>\n";

?>
```

Lastly, to gather your totals:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE question = '1';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE question = '2';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE question = '3';
```

You can adapt this to handle other form input as well, and perhaps store a long-lived session cookie to let you detect whether the same browser gets used to fill out your form multiple times.

Comment: Alright yeah I'll have to tweak this a bit but this is about what I guess I'll need to do. It's not going to be like an html document it's going to be an Android application submitting the results. So I think I was planning on just sending the message to a URL and that triggers the PHP script.

Comment: That could make things easier.  You can interpret your data however you want; that's kind of why I didn't include any actual form handling in my example PHP.  Whether you populate the `$ch` array from HTML, JSON, or just key=value pairs is up to you.  The point is that you'll handle the math to add up totals in the code that does the *reporting* rather than the *recording*.

Answer (score 1):

This could work, assuming you already have an existing file with the right number of newline characters to start you off. I do not believe however that it will maintain data integrity very well, as it could cause race conditions. To prevent race conditions, theoretically you would open the file, flock it, then write to the file. Other script instances attempting to read the flocked file will have to wait. A better approach might be using a database.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been trying to figure out if it would be better to implement a Database or if the file would suffice. I thought maybe everything came in and the script would execute in succession possible ie: one right after the other instead of parallel. Wasn't positive though hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the http_build_query function, to store the $_GET array using an string separator char like "||".

```
$data = http_build_query($_GET)."||";
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "w");
fputs ($fp, $data);
fclose ($fp);
```

To read the info stored could do this

```
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
$contents = fread($fp, filesize("counter.txt"));
fclose($fp);

$array=explode("||",$contents);

foreach($array as $var){
   parse_str($var, $data);

   //-$data contains youre stored values.
}
```

Comment: This still I guess would hit the race conditions where two instances try and access the same file at the same time. Thanks for the suggestion though.